# Javascript - Iterate key-less JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have string array converted to JSON.  It looks like

`var data = ["[None]","data","data2"]`

So, there's no key/value pair.  This causes my JSON iteration to bomb:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            var obj = data[i];
                            alert(obj);
                            for (var key in obj) {
                                var attrName = key;
                                var attrValue = obj[key];
                                alert('key: ' + attrName + 'value: ' + attrValue);
                            }

                    }
```

Should I figure out a way to key each object ([javascriptserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) created this JSON from a string array)?  Or..what do you suggest?

---

After learning a few things from you all, I am still unable to to iterate the data object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                              var obj = data[i];
                              alert(typeof obj);
                              if (typeof obj === 'object') {
                                  alert(obj);
                                  for (var key in obj) {
                                      var attrName = key;
                                      var attrValue = obj[key];
                                      alert('key: ' + attrName + 'value: ' + attrValue);
                                  }
                              }
                              else {
                                  alert(data[i]);
                              }
                          }
```

I hit the `else`, but It goes through the array 1 character at a time.  This is not what I want...

Comment: what is `data` and what is `obj`?

Comment: @Daniel A. White - `data` is defined above, look for "It looks like..." and that is the JSON.  `obj` is declared and initialized fully in the OP.

Comment: That is merely an array, not JSON.

Comment: @Diodeus - Ok, how do I iterate it?  The for loops I've tried give either all the information at once or 1 character at a time.  I want to iterate as if this was a CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is just an array:

```
var data = ["[None]","data","data2"]
for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++) {
     alert(data[x])  
}
```

Comment: Visually these are the same, but Javascript treats my data object as type `string`.  The object here is treated as typeof `object`.  So it doesn't translate.

Comment: +1 This ultimately got me to the right place. I had to add ,'json' to my jQuery `$.get()` request.  Then my return was treated as object instead of string and iterated properly.

Comment: An object is instantiated with {}, not []

Answer (score 4):

It seems you have general purpose json printer.  Usually when getting json from the server, what you do on the client is implemented with knowledge of what the json will look like.  So its a bit odd that you are trying to iterate as if the array contains object literals when it contains simple strings.

That said you can add a test to see if obj is really an object.

```
if (typeof obj === 'object') {
   // now iterate key/vals
}
```

and only iterate of the values if your `obj` is actually an object.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I said a .NET class (javascriptserializer) created this from a string array.  The Method definition says "CONVERTS AN OBJECT TO A JSON STRING".  So you all are telling me that the MSDN documentation is wrong.  This is fine.  I just need to know how to make this into "real JSON" then.

Comment: I never said any of that. An array of strings is perfectly valid json.